# Increment feature - sliding a row - mongoDb & MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I have been assigned to a new task requiring use of Auto increment in a certain way.

The requirement targets MySql and mongoDB; and I am puzzled if these DBs could address this feature natively.

The task is:
 1. Insert lines into DB (text content),
 2. Each line should have an auto-increment Index,
 3. New lines added to the end, should have their Index incremented automatically,
 4. New lines added between existing lines currently in the DB (slided-in), should be given appropriate Index-number and all lines after the newly added lines should be re-sequenced.

Example:

```
# Existing table
index |  content
---------------------
1        line-A-content-xyz    
2        line-B-content-xyz
3        line-C-content-xyz


# Updated table (Index sequence updated)
index |  content
---------------------
1        line-A-content-xyz    
2        line-EE-content-juww       (New added line)
3        line-B-content-xyz
4        line-C-content-xyz
5        line-FF-content-juww       (New added line)
```

For testing purposes, I am using mongoDB, with re-sequencing done in the code. It is Ok for testing and POC, but very inefficient for final state product.

I am wondering, if mongoDB\MySQL support Auto-increment with **slide-in** feature natively ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This would be a bit easier if this was two requirements, require an arbitrarily ordered table (use a double as an index), return table with rows (not lines) with integer numbered sequentially. Is this acceptable?

Comment: 'MySQL support Auto-increment with slide-in feature natively' - nope you have to code for it and you would have to make sure that all your FK tables also change.

Comment: 'requiring use of Auto increment in a certain way' this is not a thing. Either use autoincrement, or don't use autoincrement. Do not try to bend it to some purpose